# Should Authentication Use Cases be represented in a UC diagram?

Tags: diagrams, use-case

Should Authentication Use Cases be represented in a UC diagram?

Should there even be a use case describing authentication or, as it is usually common-sense, can it be hidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use cases should be created for any process that needs them.

Yes, this is nonspecific - the answer depends on the needs of the customer, the risk of not documenting the use case, and how much detail the team wants to document.

Generally, a use case for a common task such as authentication could be documented once, then referenced in other use cases by having a step that says "user is authenticated per use case #XYZ."

Whether to document a use case that is common sense is subjective, *unless* there is some aspect that is dissimilar to other systems. Perhaps your authentication works slightly differently: then it would certainly be worth documenting.